# Why does my Perl open() fail with "Unsuccessful open on filename containing newline"?

Tags: perl, directory

I tried to placed `${date[0]}` in my directory which is equivalent to `01252010` but `@hits` not printed. How can I managed to open the directory to get the desired output? Thanks.

ERROR:
Unsuccessful open on filename containing newline at ./total.pl line 11,  line 1.

```
#!/opt/perl/bin/perl -w

use strict;

open(FH,"/home/daily/scripts/sms_hourly_stats/date.txt");
my @date = <FH>;
print $date[0];

my $path = "/home/daily/output/sms_hourly_stats/${date[0]}/TOTAL.txt";
open(FILE,"$path") or die "Unable to open $path: $!";
my @hits = <FILE>;
print @hits;

close FH;
close FILE;
```

Comment: Listen to your error message. It says you have a filename with a newline in it, so look at $path and work your way backward until you find where the newline showed up. :)

Comment: Bright minds meets in this site:-) Hope to be better in proggamming too! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove line ending symbol. Use [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

```
chomp(my @date = <FH>);
```

Comment: alternatively you could also write chomp(@date = <FH>)

Comment: Still Unable to open /home/sudo724/reports/daily/output/sms_hourly_stats/1/TOTAL.txt

The value of ${date[0]} is 1?Thanks.

Comment: I think I got it already using chomp(my @date=<FH>). Thank you very much!:-)

Comment: I don't think you want the return value of chomp. `map {chomp; $_}`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use chomp on got values, as Ivan suggested
2. Where did you find syntax ${date[0]} ? use $date[0].

Comment: As I encountered on many scripts,there's a difference between ${date[0]} and $date[0] especially in dealing or concatenating numbers? like 
$num[0] = 3
home/dir/2009${num[0]}0 means 30
home/dir/2009$num[0]0 which is error?

Comment: ${date[0]} is "safer" in an interpolated context, but not really necessary here.  It's more useful if you have a complicated expression to expand in the interpolated string.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/opt/perl/bin/perl -w

use strict;

open(FH,"/home/daily/scripts/sms_hourly_stats/date.txt");
my @date = <FH>;
my $dir;
print ${date[0]};
chomp($dir = ${date[0]});


my $path = "/home/daily/output/sms_hourly_stats/$dir/TOTAL.txt";
open(FILE,"$path") or die "Unable to open $path: $!";
my @hits = <FILE>;
print @hits;

close FH;
close FILE;
```